# Посдкажите, принцип работы данной регулярки? "(\w)\\1+"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Надо найти какие символы дублируются.
Что означает \w понятно. Не понятно 2 косые черты \ и 1+. Поясните, пожалуйста, либо подскажите ссылку, где посмотреть

```
def duplicate_count3(text):
dup_count = re.findall("(\w)\\1+", "".join(sorted(text.lower())))
    return dup_count


input_string = 'aAbcAaBB1i11'
print(duplicate_count3(input_string))  # output ['1', 'a', 'b']
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/zlZcC2/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 слеша - просто экранирование, потому что кто-то поленился использовать raw-string. Т.е., по хорошему, там надо писать `r"(\w)\1+"`.

- `\w` - матчит букво-циферные символы *(не только, но не суть)*
- `\1` - это ссылка на группу 1, т.е. соответствует тому, чего найдётся в первых скобочках
- `+` - означает предыдущая последовательность *(\1 в данном случае)* повторяется 1 и более раз

Итого, регуляка ищет букво-циферный символ, за которым как минимум 1 раз стоит такой же символ. И возвращает то, что нашла в скобочках, т.е. только первый символ из последовательности одинаковых.